# Getting an already compiled Ruby on Rails project up and running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ide

I am a front-end developer/designer collaborating with a Rails back-end developer.  Basically I design the shell of the site and fill it into the CSS and send it to him to run the back-end.  The back-end consists of pulling xml from a repository and sending it back to be displayed on the site.

I did all of the CSS and sent him the files, and he implemented some of the back-end.

My knowledge of Rails is in-existent so I am having trouble setting up a working environment and importing the project he sent me.  He uses an IDE for his linux box, and I run off of Windows.  He sent me a zip of the project so I could have it working on my box, but have no idea how to get the working project into the editor.  I can see all of the front-end images are placed in the /public/assets/ folder but have no clue how to fully open the project and see the working environment.  Is there going to be an IDE/different OS issue or is there a way I can get this to work?

I would ask for his help but he had to take an unexpected trip and I cannot reach him.

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No IDE should be necessary. Furthermore, as long as he codes well, you shouldn't have any os issue's either.

You will may need to install the software stack, but this will very depending on his application.

Try following this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to get up and running.

The first section provides links to various required libraries, and by the end you should have all of these installed:

-[ruby](http://rubyinstaller.org/) 
-rubygems 
-rails 
-[bundler](http://gembundler.com/)

After that running the app is as easy as entering the following commands in a cmd window.

$ bundle install 
$ rails server

You can then view the app at http://localhost:3000 in your web browser.

P.S. Here is a decent guide as well http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby-on-rails/running-rails-3-on-windows/

Answer (score 1):

The structure of ruby-on-rails project is always the same for OS/IDE and change a little only from old version to new version. You could learn a little about rails project structure [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). Here's what you need:

File/Folder   Purpose

**Gemfile**    This file allows you to specify what gem dependencies are needed for your Rails application. See section on Bundler, below.

**README**  This is a brief instruction manual for your application. You should edit this file to tell others what your application does, how to set it up, and so on.

**Rakefile**    This file locates and loads tasks that can be run from the command line. The task definitions are defined throughout the components of Rails. Rather than changing Rakefile, you should add your own tasks by adding files to the lib/tasks directory of your application.

**app/**    Contains the controllers, models, views and assets for your application. You’ll focus on this folder for the remainder of this guide.

**config/** Configure your application’s runtime rules, routes, database, and more.

**config.ru**   Rack configuration for Rack based servers used to start the application.

**db/** Shows your current database schema, as well as the database migrations. You’ll learn about migrations shortly.

**doc/**    In-depth documentation for your application.

**lib/**    Extended modules for your application (not covered in this guide).

**log/**    Application log files.

**public/** The only folder seen to the world as-is. Contains the static files and compiled assets.

**script/** Contains the rails script that starts your app and can contain other scripts you use to 
deploy or run your application.

**test/**   Unit tests, fixtures, and other test apparatus. These are covered in Testing Rails Applications

**tmp/**    Temporary files
vendor/ A place for all third-party code. In a typical Rails application, this includes Ruby Gems, the Rails source code (if you install it into your project) and plugins containing additional prepackaged functionality.